# Can't scale Google Crome lower then 500px width

Tags: google-chrome, mac, html, css, web-development

I started programming about 6 months ago. When I started I was able to scale my google chrome down to a 400px width. As I started to max more website I was only able to scale my website down to 438px. I figured out that if I put my ".css" file into a "styles" folder it wouldn't let me scale my "index.html" file down to 400px anymore, But a normal Chrome website was able to go to 400px. Now Im having issues where I can't even scale my Chrome below 500px even with nothing open. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Cannot scale the Chrome program, or your website on it?

Answer (score 4):

you can resize your chrome's size by simply changing your chrome's inspector from bottom to right.

To do this, open your chrome's inspector and you can see there is a option to change your chromes Dock side to the right.

Now after changed Dock side to the right you can resize your chrome's width below 400px

Comment: Thanks very much pal, I was stuck in that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is use Device Mode in Chrome DevTools

1. Click "Toggle Device Toolbar"
2. Select Responsive option
3. Move with your mouse the sliders.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your web site at specific window sizes, open the developer tools and enable [device mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/). (It's the second icon from the left at the top of the developer tools; looks like two squares.) While in device mode, you can change the size of the viewport separately from the size of your browser window.